# Android studio doesn't show device list

Tags: flutter, android-studio, adb

My android studio doesn't show device list on my current project. But usually it does show. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

When i click run button, it says something like this:
[image]

But when i run `flutter devices` on the terminal, it says `3 connected devices`:
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Note: i'm using android studio giraffe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's my fault. I didn't check enable dart support for the project.
[image]

I checked enable dart support for the project and enable dart support for the following modules.

Comment: Glad you found a solution and shared it! You can mark it as 'accepted' by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. It helps others know that the solution worked and gives your question a 'solved' status. Welcome to Stack Overflow